# Filling up Delayed Branch slots

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

Which instruction(s) in the assembly sequences below would you place in the delay slot(s),

(A)

```
 ADD R5 <- R4, R3 
 OR R3 <- R1, R2
 SUB R7 <- R5, R6
 J    X 

 Delay Slots 

 LW R10 <- (R7)
 ADD R6 <-R1 , R2
 X:
```

Here Delay slot is 2.
But I did not get what is the Branch Condition ? Is it **Jump to X** ??? 
  If it is , then how to place 2 instruction in the delay slot ? Because to place instruction from "Before" Or " Target " or "Fall Through" , we need to compare them with Branch condition. If it is not conflicting , then we can place those instructions. Not getting meaning of J X
Ans : ADD and OR instructions.

(B)

```
 ADD R5 <- R4, R3
 OR R3 <- R1, R2
 SUB R7 <- R5, R6
 BEQ R5 <- R7, X

  Delay Slots

 LW R10 <- (R7)
 ADD R6 <- R1, R2
```

Is BEQ R5 <- R7 , X mean if X + R7  equal to R5 then take a branch X ? If yes , then we can't use SUB instruction because value of R7 will change. ADD also cant be used as R5 will change. ( means both are dependent on Branch ). OR , LW and ADD R6 <- R1 , R2 are independent on branch. Then why not LW and ADD ??
Ans says : OR and NOP.

Please guide me in these problems.

Comment: What architecture is this? Please update the tags to indicate what architecture you're using as it's not immediately obvious from just the given code.

Comment: The first answer looks wrong, how can you move the `ADD` past the `SUB` if the latter needs the former?

Comment: Tell us which chip this is.

Comment: @ all : Sorry guys but I dont know about Architecture or chip , neither , assignment mentioned such thing.

Comment: @ all : But I got hint from Jester , that ( for part (A) ) ADD can't be moved to Delayed slot as OR or SUB are directly or indirectly depends on Source and destination of ADD's registers. But Why can't  LW and ADD R6 <- R1, R2 be moved to Delayed slot. They will not affect any order.

Comment: @ all : In part (B) , Instruction ,ADD and SUB can not be moved as they depends on each other or Branch Instruction depends on them. Instruction OR can be moved as it is independent. But again why can't LW and ADD R6 <- R1 , R2  be moved ???

Comment: The `LW` and the `ADD` after it are **before** the label `X` so they must be skipped. They can't be moved into delay slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (A), `J X` is an unconditional jump to a single fixed label (presumably within the range provided by the ISA), so it does not have any data dependencies on previous instructions.

Since the `ADD` has a name dependence on the result of the `OR`, if it is to be moved after the `OR` the destination of the `OR` would have to be changed (assuming there is a free register available and that a later move can either be free in terms of scheduling or eliminated by changing the instructions that later use this value in `R3` to use the register used as the destination for the `OR`). This would be a relatively complex change and is probably excluded from consideration.

Since the `SUB` is data dependent on the `ADD` it must remain after it in the program order. Therefore the two delay slots can be filled as `OR R3 <- R1, R2; SUB R7 <- R5, R6` or `SUB R7 <- R5, R6; OR R3 <- R1, R2`. (`ADD R5 <- R4, R3; SUB R7 <- R5, R6` is disallowed because of the name dependence on `R3`; `ADD R5 <- R4, R3; OR R3 <- R1, R2` is disallowed because of the data dependence on `R5` in the `SUB` instruction.)

The unconditional nature of the jump also means that there is no fall-through path; the jump is always taken. Instructions after the delay slots will not be executed in the path reaching the jump instruction (the unconditional jump *always* jumps over them), so even if using them in the delay slots would not introduce exceptions or overwrite registers used after the jump to X there would be no advantage gained relative to using NOPs in the delay slots.

(The first part of the example code sequence may be the then clause of an if-then-else statement, being proceeded by a conditional branch that jumps to `LW R10 <- (R7)`, which would be the start of the else clause. I.e., that code may be reachable but only by a taken branch preceding the shown code.)

The unconditional nature further means that instructions could be taken from the target, though the compiler would need to ensure that all other paths to the label `X` also contain any instructions moved/copied from this target into that jump's delay slots.

The answer provided (`ADD R5 <- R4, R3; OR R3 <- R1, R2`) is simply wrong, especially since `SUB R7 <- R5, R6` is data dependent on the `ADD` instruction so that moving it before the `ADD` would produce a wrong result!

For (B), `BEQ R5 <- R7, X` is an unusual instruction, presumably meaning `if R5 == R7 goto X; R5 = old_PC+length(BEQ R5 <- R7, X)`, i.e., a branch-and-link instruction. Anyway, what gets written into R5 is not important, merely the fact that the branch overwrites R5 constrains instruction scheduling.

Since the branch instruction overwrites R5, `SUB R7 <- R5, R6` cannot be moved after the branch (i.e., the `SUB` has a name dependence; if `BEQ R8 <- R5, R7, X` was a valid form (where R8 was a free register and later uses of R5 were changed to R8) then this name dependence could be avoided).

Since the branch is data dependent on `ADD R5 <- R4, R3', that instruction cannot be moved into a delay slot.

If current value in R6 is not read by any instructions in the taken branch path, then `ADD R6 <- R1, R2` could be hoisted from the fall-through path into the second delay slot (assuming the ADD cannot produce an exception such as for overflow). This only helps performance when the branch is not taken, but it would be considered better than filling the slot with a NOP (which helps neither path).

Moving `LW R10 <- (R7)` into one of the delay slots is more problematic since the load might have a protection fault when R5 == R7 which would be avoided by the taken branch. (Technically, the run time system could be made to handle the inappropriate protection fault by looking at additional debug information accompanying the executable to discover that the load was hoisted from the fall-through path, determine that the branch would be taken, zero R10 (to avoid permission violation), and resume execution at X. However, that is a more extreme manipulation than changing register names to avoid name dependencies.)

Using instructions from the target or fall-through path of a *conditional* branch must generally preserve exception behavior. I.e., if the branch is actually taken, no instructions from the fall-through path can be allowed to generate an exception (because then an exception that would not occur without the reordering would occur with the reordering) and similarly if the branch is actually not taken, no instructions from the target path can be allowed to generate an exception.

Without information about the target path, it cannot be determined if `SUB R7 <- R5, R6` is the last reader of `R6` (i.e., `R6` is dead after that point). However, if one found an instruction in the target path using `R6` as a destination before any instruction used it as a source, then `R6` would be dead and (assuming that `ADD` cannot generate an exception) `ADD R6 <- R1, R2` could be used in one of the delay slots.

Depending on the ISA (and opcodes used, e.g., MIPS has overflow exceptions for signed addition instructions but not for unsigned — the result is otherwise the same since twos-complement format is used) an addition may generate an overflow exception (but I assumed that such was not the case). With some form of memory protection implemented by the hardware, a memory read can generate a protection exception. Generally the compiler has to assume that a branch might be preventing such a protection exception (such as going past the end of an array or dereferencing a null pointer), so it generally cannot use a memory access from either the target (in case the branch is not taken) or the fall-through (in case the branch is taken). (Avoiding unnecessary page faults in a virtual memory system would generally be desired for performance but might not be considered strictly necessary for correctness.)

As noted, a somewhat sophisticated runtime system could correct such exceptions, at least for loads, but such "heroic" measures are probably considered outside the scope of this type of exercise.

In some cases, the compiler could determine that a load is safe (e.g., a load within the current stack frame) even though it is guarded by a conditional branch, but for such exercises one would generally assume the compiler cannot guarantee the safety of such memory accesses. If the path with the load is likely, the compiler could use a prefetch instruction in the delay slot to reduce cache miss latency; however, in this example a prefetch would only reduce the miss latency by two cycles assuming a scalar pipeline. Prefetches are nops on a cache hit or protection violation, so such might frequently give no advantage relative to using a nop  — and could degrade performance by introducing cache misses when the branch is taken — but are safe in terms of exception behavior.

So the delay slots could either be `OR R3 <- R1, R2; OR R3 <- R3, R3` (i.e., `OR` and `NOP`) or, if R6 is dead after `SUB R7 <- R5, R6` (and overflow exceptions are not an issue), `OR R3 <- R1, R2; ADD R6 <- R1, R2`. The given answer seems to assume that the compiler cannot determine that `R6` is dead, which is a reasonable assumption given no knowledge of the code on the taken path. (In reality, the compiler would be able to examine that code and `R6` might — or might not — be dead.)

Comment: I got your point but sorry still confused with fall thorough instruction      LW and      ADD R6 <-R1 , R2. Can you explain about these 2 instructions for both example.

Comment: @user1745866 Did the edit clarify the need to preserve exception behavior (or just make the matter *more* confusing by adding further complications ☹)?